# Why is 7-Zip failing during this Chocolatey installation on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, chocolatey

I am trying to install Chocolatey

```
https://chocolatey.org/install
```

and using the command:

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

It is showing error:

```
Unable to unzip package using 7zip. Perhaps try setting $env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = 'true' and call install
again. Error: 7-Zip encountered a fatal error while extracting the files
At line:221 char:9
+     2 { throw "$errorMessage 7-Zip encountered a fatal error while ex ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Unable to unzip...cting the files:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unable to unzip package using 7zip. Perhaps try setting $env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompres
   sion = 'true' and call install again. Error: 7-Zip encountered a fatal error while extracting the files
```

I have 7zip installed.

Comment: Can you try the suggestion in the error message (set `$env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = 'true'` and try again)? Maybe try the PowerShell install command, too, and let us know how that goes?

Comment: There is a download of 7za.exe that unpacks the package during the installation.

Comment: Also, after running this have you looked at your error array using `$Error`. Are there any suspicious errors before that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few months, i ran the same command from cmd with *Administrative Privilege* and it worked. The main point was running

> cmd.exe As an Administrator.

Answer (score 10):

**I encounter the same issue.**

Running window `cmd` as administrator may be a solution for some but in my case i had to update my window system environment variable, 
I just added this to exiting value on 
**path:** `$env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = 'true'` 
and all works just fine.

Comment: @prashant thakre, am glad my answer was helpful. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when I was trying to install chocolatey on multiple servers which was finally getting blocked at chocolatey server, which is a chocolatey feature.

https://chocolatey.org/docs/community-packages-disclaimer#rate-limiting

Hence the downloaded file is null and cannot be unzipped. The block is lifted an hour later. After rate limit is lifted, the errors disappears until you trigger it again.

Rate limiting also applies to other packages. When limit is hit while downloading a package other than chocolatey itself, you will get an error code 429.

https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting#im-getting-a-429-too-many-requests-issue-when-attempting-to-use-the-community-package-repository

Answer (score 1):

First answer: Running window cmd as administrator may be a solution for some but in my case i had to update my window system environment variable, I just added this to exiting value on path: $env:chocolateyUseWindowsCompression = 'true' and all works just fine.

may not work immediately and you still receive "Unable to unzip package using 7zip." error.

Try again after restarting your machine. In my case command works after restarting.

Thx
karam

Comment: You need to put more effort into answering a question. You have answered a question that is two years old and has been viewed 2402 times. Provide clear instructions so that if someone else has a similar issue, your answer could work for them too.

Comment: Ok, the very first answer given by Harrison is correct, but the only twist is that it will not reflect immediately. You need to restart the machine to reflect the environment variable, after restart run the same command and Chocolate will be installed.